# What does the Aztec word "calpuleque" mean?

Tags: mesoamerica, aztec

What does the Aztec word "calpuleque" mean? Who does it refer to? What is its relationship with the words "calpulli", "alteptl" and "tlaotani"?

Comment: I think this could have been asked a bit more elaborately, in order for it to fit the definition of a History site (rather than being a language question).  That said, re: mods, this language is very rare and most of it's usage is situated within a historical context — even, to some degree, when it is used in the present.

Answer (score 3):

All these words refer to the hierarchical organization of the society.

"Tlatoani" was the title of the ruler. The word derives from the local "nahuatl" language and denotes a spokesman. Huey tlatoani was the really highest one.

"Altepetl" was the city state, a local ethnically based province. The word is a combination of words for "water" and "mountain".

These city states were divided to "calpulli" ("suburbs") whose top executives were known as "calpuleque". There were also additional pipiltin (noblemen).